# Rails JQuery not rendering Javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am a newbie at Javascript, JQuery, and to a lesser extent, Rails.  I trying to add some interactive behavior to my existing Rails app but for now am just trying to get it to render the following test:

myteams.js.erb:

```
page.alert('Hi')
```

My controller includes the following:

```
def myteams

    if (params[:command] == "accept")
      invite = TeamUser.find(params[:id])
      invite.confirmed = true
      invite.save
    end

    if (params[:command] == "delete")
      invite = TeamUser.find(params[:id])
      invite.destroy
      @teams = current_user.teams
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

The link that calls the code in myteams.html.erb:

```
<%=link_to image_tag("delete.png"), {:controller => "teams", :action => "myteams", :id => teamAssociation.id, :command => "delete"}, :class => "deleteTeam", :remote => :true %>
```

and my application.js includes:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")} })
```

When I click the link, the team is deleted from the database but nothing happens on screen - no reload, no alert prompt.  I am loading the jQuery files in application.html.erb.  I have no idea why this simple test is not working.  Please help and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing simply
`alert('Hi')` in `myteams.js.erb`

Answer (score 2):

`:remote => :true` should be `:remote => true`.

And by the way, you'd better divide your action into two.